# Two multicast streams sharing the same group address

Tags: linux, udp, multicast

I see two different multicast streams with the same group address `226.a.b.c`, but different ports `A` and `B`, arriving at my machine.

I need only one of those (`A` for example). 
So I `bind` my socket to `226.a.b.c:A` and do a join request with `setsockopt IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`

Now I expect to receive only packets addressed to the port `A` and all the packets addressed to the port `B` to be dropped. Am I correct or is there any problem with this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the bound socket will receive only packets addressed to 226.a.b.c:A.
Packets addressed to 226.a.b.c:B still can be received by some other socket (even in another process), that is, they are not necessarily dropped.